# Windows RT/Universal app, Checking Stock from yahoo finance

Tags: .net, yahoo-finance, win-universal-app

recently I've been trying to make a Universal app which checks stock price of a certain company. Currently I'm working with Windows Phone 8.1 ( I will start windows 8.1 once I get this working for Windows Phone 8.1). I'm using Yahoo finance, to get the stock. The problem is that its on csv format, which I can't figure out how to use. I have made this with appinventor before and now Im trying to do the same thing. I'm not a very good programmer so.. yeah.. can I get some help?

```
 private async void CheckStock_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(); // Add: using System.Net.Http;
        var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv&s="+StockEnter.Text));
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        ActualStock.Text = (result.ToString());
    }
```

Everything works, but Instead of just showing the stock, it shows everything!:
Here is an example: I tried checking stock for Microsoft.
http://snag.gy/cLDGr.jpg
How do I just make it show "47,98", which is the stock of microsoft.

Comment: You could split the string by the delimiter , and then use the second part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the short answer to this is that you should extract the second part of the result and show that. This can be done by splitting the string by the delimiter `,`, and then using the second part.

```
string[] values = result.ToString().Split(",");
string stockValue = values[1]; // values are 0-indexed, so 1 is the second string
ActualStock.Text = stockValue;
```

Comment: Thanks, found a similar method but this seems simper!!